# Ubuntu 22.04 efibootmgr from terminal 'eats' slashes

Tags: command-line, uefi, bootloader, filename, efibootmgr

I'm running ubuntu 22.04.3 + maintenance on a DELL XPS 9320 (unix variant), efibootmgr version 17, GNU bash version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Here's the output from my last attempt to set a loader in efibootmgr:

```
$ sudo efibootmgr -v -b 0006 -L alternate -l "\\EFI\\ubuntu\\shimx64.efi" -d /dev/nvme0n1
BootCurrent: 0005
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0006,0005,0000,0002,0001,0003,0004
Boot0000  ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,cf3c865e-ea2b-40ea-a869-6c5d9634756d,0x22,0x77338)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* Linux Firmware Updater    HD(1,GPT,cf3c865e-ea2b-40ea-a869-6c5d9634756d,0x22,0x77338)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\fwupdx64.efi)
Boot0002* UEFI PC SN810 NVMe WDC 2048GB 230994444307 1  HD(1,GPT,cf3c865e-ea2b-40ea-a869-6c5d9634756d,0x22,0x77338)/File(\EFI\Boot\BootX64.efi)N.....YM....R,Y.
Boot0003* PEBOOT    HD(1,GPT,d120a4ac-d9f3-450e-9569-3df52d5b6b9e,0x22,0x77338)/File(\EFI\PEBoot\bootx64.efi)
Boot0004  UEFI HTTPs Boot   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x6)/MAC(000000000000,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)/Uri()N.....YM....R,Y.
Boot0005* rEFInd Boot Manager   HD(1,GPT,cf3c865e-ea2b-40ea-a869-6c5d9634756d,0x22,0x77338)/File(\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi)
Boot0006* alternate HD(1,GPT,cf3c865e-ea2b-40ea-a869-6c5d9634756d,0x22,0x77338)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
```

Note BOOT0006 has a file name missing any slashes. It should be the same as BOOT0000 save the entry name **alternate** instead of **ubuntu**.

This my problem: getting efibootmgr to include the necessary separators in the boot path name.  I've tried unquoting and quoting the **-l** operand, using forward and reverse slashes, and doubling them.

Something (shell?, terminal?, efibootmgr?) somewhere seems to be removing them!

Comment: On my Arch Linux system, I've been using `efibootmgr ... --loader /EFI/Linux/arch-linux.efi` for a while now, so the normal slashes work for me (shows up as `File(\EFI\Linux\arch-linux.efi)` in the output)

Comment: Also I delete (`-B`) and then recreate entries - it seems using the `-b` option to try and update an existing boot entry doesn't work very well: https://github.com/rhboot/efibootmgr/issues/161

Comment: @muru You're right; -B seems flaky.  Totally deleting the bad entry then adding it back gives the same result -- slashes get eaten.